# Does AWS store users' passwords without hashing?

Tags: aws

I just noticed that AWS provides a service that checks your users' passwords for corporate password rule compliance "periodically": https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/iam-password-policy.html

This makes me afraid that AWS stores encrypted passwords instead of storing hashes of passwords. Is that the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Checks if the account password policy for IAM users meets the specified requirements indicated in the parameters.

What is being checked is the account password **policy**, not the actual passwords of users.  It's a periodic check to make sure you're requiring the level of complexity that you want to be requiring.  As such, no need for reversible encryption of user passwords.